# Argument of type '"content"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TemplateRef<any>'.ts(2345)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to open a modal when I click on a button.  But I cannot pass the template reference to my modal.  I am getting a type error in the nav.component.ts

In my nav.component.html

```
<button *ngIf="!loggedIn" class="btn btn-outline-success ms-3" (click)="open()">
    Sign Up
</button>
```

In nav.component.ts : **EDITED**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.scss']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public modalShared : ModalComponent
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void { 
  }

  open() {
    this.modalShared.openModal("'content'");
  }

}
```

In my modal.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef, Input, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.scss']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {

  modalRef: BsModalRef = new BsModalRef();

  constructor(
    private modalService: BsModalService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  openModal(template:TemplateRef<any>){
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
  } 

}
```

And my modal.component.html

```
<ng-template #content>
    <p>Click button is working!</p>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Can you add more code of `nav.component.ts` like where you declared `this,modalShared`?

Comment: @Yogesh, I've edited it and added more code in the ```nav.component.ts```

Answer (score 1):

you are passing string instead of expected TemplateREf. You need to use @ViewChild to get the reference to templateRef.

```
@ViewChild('content')
content: TemplateRef<any>;

...

open() {
  this.modalShared.openModal(this.content);
}
```

Comment: Still getting an error.  "Argument of type 'TemplateRef<any> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TemplateRef<any>'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'TemplateRef<any>'.ts(2345)"

Comment: `@Viewchild('content') content!: TemplateRef<any>`